# Using null-coalescing as a replacement for try catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, null-coalescing-operator

How come I get an invalid cast exception when trying to set a `NULL` value returned from the database inside `Comments` which is of type `Int32`.

I am trying to replace this:

```
                try
                {
                    objStreamItem.Comments = (Int32)sqlReader["Comments"];
                    if (objStreamItem.Comments > 0) { 
                        listComments = Comment.GetAll(objStreamItem.Id);

                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException)
                {
                    // Execute if "Comments" returns NULL
                    listComments = null;
                    objStreamItem.Comments = 0;
                }
```

With this:

```
Comments = ((Int32?)sqlReader["Comments"]) ?? 0
```

The two are in different contexts, but you should get the idea. Instead of using a try catch block I am trying to solve this in a more elegant way.

Thanks.

### UPDATE

It is stored as a nullable integer in the database.

```
    public int? Comments
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

### I just want to thank everyone who answered or posted on this question, everything was very informative. thanks!

Comment: Is `Comments` defined as nullable?

Comment: are your comments being truly stored as integers or text / string / varchar..? also please show where you are first declaring Comments is it's type nullable just curious

Comment: Is it being returned as a DBNull?

Comment: If it's already stored as an `int?`, why do you need to cast it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose a ternary expression is the way to go here

```
objStreamItem.Comments = sqlReader["Comments"] is DBNull ? 0 : (Int32)sqlReader["Comments"] ;
```

You could also store the return value of `sqlReader["Comments"]` in a variable first to shorten the expression

```
var comments = sqlReader["Comments"];
objStreamItem.Comments = comments is DBNull ? 0 : (Int32)comments;
```

Comment: that's a very clean solution.

Answer (score 7):

Your SQL reader is returning `DBNull` when the value is null; There's no conversion from `DBNull` to `int?`, and the null-coalescing operator doesn't recognize `DBNull.Value` as something that needs to be coalesced.

**EDIT 3**

(Another problem with your original code: It will assume that "Comments" returned null if "Comments" is non-null but `GetAll()` throws an `InvalidCastException`.)

As hvd points out, you can use the as operator with nullable types:

```
objStreamItem.Comments = sqlReader["Comments"] as int?;
listComments = (objStreamItem.Comments ?? 0) > 0 ? Comment.GetAll(objStreamItem.ID) : null;
```

You could save yourself from all of this, however, if you simply defined `Comment.GetAll()` to return an empty list or a null reference when the ID you pass to it has no comments.

Answer (score 2):

The `??` operator checks for `null`, but `sqlReader["Comments"]` won't ever be `null`. It will either be an `Int32`, or a `DBNull`. You can cast `null` to `Int32?`, but you cannot do so with `DBNull.Value`. You can use `sqlReader["Comments"] as Int32?` instead, which checks if the result can be converted to `Int32`, and if not, assigns `null`.

Comment: `as` can only be used with reference types.

Comment: No, `as` really does work with nullable types too. I'm not aware of that being a new feature, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Ah, learn something new every day.  It's not a new feature; the as and is operators were extended to support nullable types when nullable types were introduced.

Comment: That's odd.  Where did you look it up?  I also looked it up, and found the document at this link, which claims to be a C#2.0 spec and says that the `is` and `as` operators support nullable types: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/f/98fdf0c7-2bbd-40d3-9fd1-5a4159fa8044/csharp%202.0%20specification_sept_2005.doc

Comment: That's the document I found, and I think I misread. Take a look at 20.8.5: "The as operator can be used with a type parameter T as the right hand side only if T is known to be a reference type (§20.7)." However, from that same document, see 24.3.6: "The as operator (§7.9.10) is extended to support nullable types. In an operation of the form e as T, e must be an expression and T must be a reference type, a type parameter known to be a reference type, or a nullable type." I found the first, but missed the second.

Answer (score 1):

That statement tries to perform the cast before coalescing the values. You need to add parenthesis. Judging by your example above, it also looks like the field is an `int` rather than an `int?`:

```
Comments = (Int32)(sqlReader["Comments"] ?? 0);
```